# How to update img src using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image

User clicks on link, which is image of an empty checkbox. Here is my HTML:

```
<a href="" class="completeTask" id="<?php echo $task->id ?>" name="taskStatus">
<img src="<?php echo ( $task->complete == 1 ) ? "/images/task-checkbox-filled.png" : "/images/task-checkbox-empty.png" ?>" class="task-checkbox" />
</a>
```

.js script is called:

```
$( function() {

 $( ".completeTask" ).click( function() {

    var taskID = $( this ).attr( "id" );
    var name = $( this ).attr( "name" );
    var data = "taskID=" + taskID;
    var parent = $( this );
    var image = $( ".task-checkbox" );

    if ( name == "completeTask" ) {

        $.ajax( {

            type: "POST",
            url: "/scripts/completeTask.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,

            success: function( imageSource ) {
                image.attr( 'src', imageSource );
            }
        } );
    }

    return false;
} );
} );
```

The result returned by completeTsk.php is an image path and filename:

```
    //Return image path and filename
    if ( $task->complete == 1 )
        echo "/images/task-checkbox-filled.png";
    else
        echo "/images/task-checkbox-empty.png";

    exit;
```

My expected result is that a new image of a filled checkbox is loaded up, but instead when the user clicks on the original empty checkbox, the image disappears.

Comment: What do you get if you do `console.log(imageSource)` in the success callback .. Also check for any errors in the console if you don't log anything

Comment: Also, check the element in something like Firebug or Chrome's version (forget the name) and see if the src is indeed being changed to expected link. Also set your datatype to text on your ajax options.

Comment: Also check the output in the Net section, perhaps your php script is outputting more than you expect.

Comment: inspect your ajax response (net tab on Chrome Inspector) and inspect the img tag after the script has ran, to see what the src attribute's value is. Or the path to the image could be wrong...

Comment: You should set `dataType:"text"`, because without that jQuery will try to guess the type from the mime type (which I guess you're not setting) and automatically convert it.

Comment: oh and you should also check for extra characters being printed by your PHP (like newlines, error messages, etc.)

Comment: To extend what Dave just said, you could do something like `echo(json_encode("your string"))` which will ensure a clean string return. I think that's the command i've used anyway. Prolly a better one, but sure i've used that before. or maybe htmlentities?